# WCF TCP Windows Authentication issue

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, authentication, tcp

I have a situation where I have 2 Machines.

- Machine A
- Machine B

Client on machine B connects successfully to Host on machine A.

Client on machine B be connects successfully to Host on machine B.

Client on machine A connects successfully to Host on machine B.

Client on machine A **CANNOT** connect to Host on machine A.  - **System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: The server has rejected the client credentials.**

I am using Windows authentication.

**Client:**

```
        var netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding()
        {
            Security = new NetTcpSecurity()
            {
                Mode = SecurityMode.Transport,
                Transport = new TcpTransportSecurity()
                {
                    ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Windows,
                }
            },
            TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = long.MaxValue,
            MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
            MaxBufferPoolSize = long.MaxValue,
            ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
            {
                MaxDepth = int.MaxValue,
                MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue,
                MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue
            },
            SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
            ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue
        };

        string endpointAddress;
        if (port == 0)
            endpointAddress = string.Format("net.tcp://{0}/Configuration", host);
        else
            endpointAddress = string.Format("net.tcp://{0}:{1}/Configuration", host, port);

        Console.WriteLine("Endpoint: {0}", endpointAddress);

        var factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyChannel>(netTcpBinding);
        factory.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(endpointAddress), new DnsEndpointIdentity("MyDns"));

        //Do not verify
        factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;

        factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = domain;
        factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = username;
        factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = password;

        //Console.WriteLine("Opening Channel Factory ... ");
        factory.Open();
```

**Host:**

```
    #region INIT

    //Set configuration file just once
    if (ChannelServices.RegisteredChannels.Length == 0)
    {
        RemotingConfiguration.Configure(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile, false);
    }

    _serviceHost = null;
    _serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyChannel));
    _serviceHost.AddDefaultEndpoints();

    // build list with local IP addresses to bind to
    var localIpAddresses = new List<IPAddress>(Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()));
    if (IPAddress.Loopback != null)
        localIpAddresses.Add(IPAddress.Loopback);
    localIpAddresses.RemoveAll(i => i.AddressFamily != AddressFamily.InterNetwork);

    // enable metadata exchange bahaviour
    // add metadatabehaviour in case HTTP is not enabled
    var metadataBehaviour = _serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
    if (metadataBehaviour == null)
    {
        metadataBehaviour = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        _serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(metadataBehaviour);
    }

    var credentialsBehaviour = _serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceCredentials>();
    if (credentialsBehaviour == null)
    {
        credentialsBehaviour = new ServiceCredentials();
        _serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(credentialsBehaviour);
    }

    var serviceDebug = _serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
    if (serviceDebug == null)
    {
        serviceDebug = new ServiceDebugBehavior();
        _serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceDebug);
    }
    serviceDebug.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;

    var tcpPort = "9096";

    _log.Info("tcpPort - {0}", tcpPort);

    var netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding()
    {
        Security = new NetTcpSecurity()
        {
            Mode = SecurityMode.Transport,
            Transport = new TcpTransportSecurity()
            {
                ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Windows,
            }
        },
        TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed,
        MaxReceivedMessageSize = long.MaxValue,
        MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
        MaxBufferPoolSize = long.MaxValue,
        ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
        {
            MaxDepth = int.MaxValue,
            MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue,
            MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue
        },
        SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
        ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue
    };

    var endpoint = _serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
        typeof(IMyChannel),
        netTcpBinding,
        new Uri(string.Format("net.tcp://0:{0}/Configuration", tcpPort)));

    ServiceSecurityAuditBehavior newAudit = new ServiceSecurityAuditBehavior();
    newAudit.AuditLogLocation = AuditLogLocation.Application;
    newAudit.MessageAuthenticationAuditLevel = AuditLevel.SuccessOrFailure;
    newAudit.ServiceAuthorizationAuditLevel = AuditLevel.SuccessOrFailure;
    newAudit.SuppressAuditFailure = false;

    _serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
        MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding(),
        string.Format("net.tcp://localhost:{0}/Configuration/mex", tcpPort));

    _serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Remove<ServiceSecurityAuditBehavior>();
    _serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(newAudit);

    _serviceHost.Opening += (sender, eventArgs) => _log.Info("Opening Connection ...");
    _serviceHost.Opened += (sender, eventArgs) => _log.Info("Opened Connection ...");

    _serviceHost.Closing += (sender, eventArgs) => _log.Info("Closing connection ...");
    _serviceHost.Closed += (sender, eventArgs) => _log.Info("Closed connection ...");

    _serviceHost.Faulted += (sender, eventArgs) => _log.Error("Fault detected on WCF host");

    _serviceHost.Open();
    #endregion
```

**Here is my full stack trace:**

> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: The server
>   has reject ed the client credentials. --->
>   System.Security.Authentication.InvalidCredential Exception: The server
>   has rejected the client credentials. ---> System.Component
>   Model.Win32Exception: The logon attempt failed    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] message,
>   LazyAsyn cResult lazyResult)    at
>   System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message,
>   LazyAsyncResul t lazyResult)    at
>   System.Net.Security.NegoState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextSend(Byte[]
>   message , LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)    at
>   System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] message,
>   LazyAsyn cResult lazyResult)    at
>   System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message,
>   LazyAsyncResul t lazyResult)    at
>   System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyRe sult)    at
>   System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.AuthenticateAsClient(NetworkCredential
>   credential, String targetName, ProtectionLevel
>   requiredProtectionLevel, TokenIm personationLevel
>   allowedImpersonationLevel)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider.WindowsS
>   treamSecurityUpgradeInitiator.OnInitiateUpgrade(Stream stream,
>   SecurityMessagePr operty& remoteSecurity)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---
>
> Server stack trace:    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider.WindowsS
>   treamSecurityUpgradeInitiator.OnInitiateUpgrade(Stream stream,
>   SecurityMessagePr operty& remoteSecurity)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamSecurityUpgradeInitiatorBase.InitiateUp
>   grade(Stream stream)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionUpgradeHelper.InitiateUpgrade(Strea
>   mUpgradeInitiator upgradeInitiator, IConnection& connection,
>   ClientFramingDecode r decoder, IDefaultCommunicationTimeouts
>   defaultTimeouts, TimeoutHelper& timeout Helper)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamedFramingRequestChannel.SendPreamble(IC
>   onnection connection, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper,
>   ClientFramingDecoder decoder , SecurityMessageProperty&
>   remoteSecurity)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamedFramingRequestChannel.StreamedConnect
>   ionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection connection,
>   TimeoutHelper& time outHelper)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(Time
>   Span timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamedFramingRequestChannel.StreamedFraming
>   Request.SendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeS pan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean on eway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan tim eout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCall
>   Message methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   req Msg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgDa ta, Int32 type)    at MyProject.TestConnection()    at
>   MyProject.Program.ManualInput() in d:\Source\MyProject\Program.cs:line
>   84

It does not make any sense.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

K

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

This issue was that DnsEndpointIdentity is not needed for windows authentication :)